# How to support orientation in iOS 5 and 6 without having to modify every single view controller file?

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, uiviewcontroller, orientation

My iPad app is set to support both landscape orientations (left and right).  When I run it in the 6.0 or 6.1 simulator it behaves as expected.  But in 5.1, it is locked to portrait (up or down, I can't tell) and doesn't re-orient when the simulator is rotated.

Edit:  This has been marked as duplicate to this question:  [Supporting both iOS 6 and iOS 5 autorotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12434992/supporting-both-ios-6-and-ios-5-autorotation/13800907#13800907)

I'm changing the question to ask, how can this be done without having to add this function:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);
}
```

To every view controller?

Comment: That is because the way orientation is handled is different between iOS5 and iOS6. I found this answer helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13800907/620197

Comment: return YES in shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation

Answer (score 3):

You need to override the below method like this to support orientation as per your requirement in ios 5.1 and early versions...

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Bhanu.  I've changed the question now as its a dupe.

Comment: +1 for Bhanu Prakash ,Does any one know for iOS 7 Compatible as well?