# Play video on landscape and force app return to portrait

Tags: iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller, landscape, landscape-portrait

I used MPMoviePlayerViewController to play a video and when back to app, I need app force return portrait

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to solve this is by using
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13800907/620197

These are callbacks who only gets called when the user autorotates - you can tell the user to rotate the device and then the autorotate callback will be called and will show only the supported orientation.

If you still want force rotation i believe you need to dismiss the controller - try this and please do tell me if it worked out for you:
[IOS 6 force device orientation to landscape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12640870/ios-6-force-device-orientation-to-landscape)

I have searched the web for a long time for a force rotation solution that will please me with no success, it almost looks like apple
Doesnt want us to be able to so this.