# orientation issue iOS 5

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiinterfaceorientation

I have created an iPad application that only supports `landscape orientation` (left and right).Ìt works perfectly on `iOS 6`, but on `iOS 5` the application is turned.

Could any one please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12434992/supporting-both-ios-6-and-ios-5-autorotation

Comment: How have you already specified the orientation changes? I've found adding the supported orientations in the applications InfoPlist works for iOS5/6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add following method in `ViewController`

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:
    (UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation {
         return (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft ||
     toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
}
```

---

`shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` method deprecated in iOS 6, still needed for iOS 5 support.

Comment: Actually it works but when I use presentViewController function, the app turns again

Comment: Add same method in `ViewController` which is presented by `presentViewController` method.

Answer (score 0):

If your app uses a UINavigationController, then you should subclass it and set the class in IB. You would then want to override the following methods to support both iOS5 and iOS6:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation;
{
  return interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft ||
 interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations;
{
  return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft | UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
}

- (BOOL) shouldAutorotate;
{
  return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in ios 6 their are "shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation" method deprecated,so u want to run  the build in ios 5 and ios 6.

then,please go to build phase section and open the compile source.

then,paste the line in all viewcontroller

-fno-objc-arc

After that u paste the code

```
       - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:
(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation {
     return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft ||
 interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
   }
```

and make sure that in summary page support interface orientation are only select landscape left and right.

Comment: Why do you recommend setting -fno-objc-arc? I think it doesn't have anything to do with autorotation.

Comment: it run deprecated method in ios 6 and u can say that old ios method run in newer version which has deprecated.

Comment: No, it disables ARC for particular file. Did you mean -Wno-deprecated?

Answer (score 0):

In your **applicationDidFinishLaunching** method put this code

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] setOrientation:UIDeviceOrientationLandscape];
```

This will set you application to landscape mode irrespective of the device.