# UIInterfaceOrientation remains in portrait

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiinterfaceorientation

I've got a header/brand image which *changes between iPad and iPhone*, but *will not change the picture when changing from portrait to landscape*, which is really important that it does.

I have this HeaderView Class, which is called by tableViewControllers like this:

```
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = [[HeaderView alloc] initWithText:@""];
```

which holds a UIImageView:

```
@interface HeaderView : UIImageView{

}
- (id)initWithText:(NSString*)text;
- (void)setText:(NSString*)text;


@end
```

For the M file, we find where I'm not getting the result I want:

```
#import "HeaderView.h"

#define IDIOM    UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()
#define IPAD     UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad
@interface HeaderView()
{
    UILabel*label;
}
@end

@implementation HeaderView 

- (id)initWithText:(NSString*)text
{
    UIImage* img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"WashU.png"];
    UIImage* iPhonePortrait = [UIImage imageNamed:@"WashU2.png"];
    UIImage* image = [[UIImage alloc] init];


    UIInterfaceOrientation interfaceOrientation = [UIApplication     sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;

        //different header image for different devices...
    if(IDIOM==IPAD){
        image = img;
    }
    else{
        if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(interfaceOrientation)){
        image = iPhonePortrait;
        }
        else if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation))
        {
            iPhonePortrait = nil;
            image = img;
        } 
    }    
    [headerImageView setImage:image];
    if (self = [super initWithImage:image]){

    }

    return self;
}
```

I also have added these methods:

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation         {
    return YES;
}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return YES;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
```

I'm sure its a classic sort of question, but I'm reasonably stumped. Also, if I remove

```
[headerImageView setImage:image];
```

, and

```
[self addSubview:headerImageView];
```

, the image still shows up, which means that

```
if (self = [super initWithImage:image])
```

is doing all the display work.

Comment: If the 'img' and the 'iPhonePortrait' are identical besides a 90 degree rotation, then the rotation might be occurring but you can't tell.  That is, you install the 'iPhonePortrait' but the UI rotates it 90 back to 'img' - end result is that it appears nothing happened...  Possible solution thus is: don't change 'image' (just like you did for iPad), let the UI do the rotation.

Comment: They are not identical images, but quite different.

Comment: Does the answer from this SO question help you?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12540152/iphone-ipad-app-orientation

Answer (score 0):

didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation is sent to your view controller after rotation, you can implement that to change your image.

```
-(void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{
      ...change your image here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not actually assigning the image to the imageView.   Add:

```
headerImageView.image = image;
```

somewhere after 'image' has been set (based on iPad vs iPhone and Portrait vs Landscape).

Comment: Thank you for your consideration, though this may have solved part of the problem, we're not cooking with gas yet.

Comment: You are adding the image to both the headerView and 'self' (with initWithImage).  I really should only be in one.  Also, how do you know that the headerView is actually viewable - you haven't set coordinates, etc.  If your coordinates are messed up, then when rotating some stuff might drop off outside of the view.

Comment: You are correct... the subview has nothing to do with displaying the image but this: does...

if (self = [super initWithImage:image])
{

}

Answer (score 0):

As your code, you do not need allocate (UIImage*)image property, because you will assign (UIImage*)img or (UIImage*)iPhonePortrait. And should assign image to headerImageView.image.

```
[headerImageView setImage:image];
```