# How to subclass Navigation Controller when using storyboards?

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard, uiinterfaceorientation, subclassing

I'm using storyboards in interface builder using the Xcode menu 'Editor...Embed in...Navigation Controller'.

It seems that in iOS 6 you have to subclass the UINavigationController to allow all orientations, with

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll   );
}
```

But how do I subclass the UINavigationController with a storyboard app as there is no reference to it in the code?

Comment: In Interface Builder, select the UINavigationController then in  Identity Inspector tab 3 on right side, change class to your CustomNavigationController name.

Comment: UINavigationController supports all orientations in iOS6.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can select the navigation controller scene's navigation controller from the storyboard:

[image]

And then use the identity inspector on the right to change the class:

[image]

For instance change the "Class" there to `MyCustomNavigationController` and then just create a new class in your project called `MyCustomNavigationController`:

**MyCustomNavigationController.h**:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MyCustomNavigationController : UINavigationController
@end
```

**MyCustomNavigationController.m**:

```
@implementation MyCustomNavigationController

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}

... any other methods you want ...

@end
```