# iOS 6: Unable to force portrait mode generally and landscape mode in one single view

Tags: ios6, orientation, landscape-portrait, autorotate

I am searching the whole net for days, but can't find an answer.

The problem is: I can't force my app to present ALL UIViewControllers just in portrait mode, except one UIViewController, which should be able to work in every of the 4 modes.

Those are my options:

- iOS 6
- UINavigationController
- UITabBarController
- Storyboard
- All modes are enabled in the project (also in Info.plist)

I already tried

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
```

but it does not even seem to work..

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer:

- Subclass UINavigationController (https://stackoverflow.com/a/12999017/1011125) OR UITabBarController if used.
- Set up the orientations (https://stackoverflow.com/a/12539784/1011125).

That's it :).