# How to subclass a UINavigationController?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I'm using [AMScrollingNavbar](https://github.com/andreamazz/AMScrollingNavbar) to hide my Navigation Bar when scrolling. However, I'm stuck at at the part where it mentioned:

> Make sure to use a subclass of ScrollingNavigationController for your
>   UINavigationController. Either set the class of your
>   UINavigationController in your storyboard, or create programmatically
>   a ScrollingNavigationController instance in your code.

I've tried many ways to do it.

1. I tried to add `ScrollingNavigationController` in my `UITableViewController` of the controller that I want the navigation bar to collapse. However it throws an error `Use of undeclared type ScrollingNavigationController`.
2. I tried to add an instance of `ScrollingNavigationController` inside my `UITableViewController`, but same error of `Use of undeclared type ScrollingNavigationController`.

Tried searching online for solution, but can't find any. Appreciate your help!

**EDIT:**

```
class PostScreenNC: UINavigationController, ScrollingNavigationController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    if let navigationController = navigationController as? ScrollingNavigationController {
        navigationController.followScrollView(tableView, delay: 50.0)
    }
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you using storyboard or loading ViewControllers programmatically ??

Comment: I tried both, but no luck. Any solution would be good.

Comment: I suggest you try their demo first, it clearly show how to implement this in storyboard

Comment: try this. It will help you  http://stackoverflow.com/a/12999017/6655153

Comment: @Tj3n Where can I get the demo? The only demo I see is the video of trying the repo out.

Comment: download the zip files in the github page and open it, the demo is in there

Comment: I'm not sure what is the issue. But i feel your Navigation Controller should have ScrollingNavigationController as parent controller. Here i think you are trying in view controller, which should have been done in UINavigationControllerClass.