# preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation not getting called

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiinterfaceorientation

I have a scenario in which I have a UITabbarController with 5 tabs. Each tab contains a UINavigationController.

Now in one of the UINavigationController rootViewController, when I select an option, another viewcontroller is pushed. Now I want the another view controller to be Landscape only.

Following is the code of my UITabBarController n UINavigationController category for Orientation

```
@implementation UITabBarController (rotation)

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    if ([self.selectedViewController respondsToSelector:@selector(shouldAutorotate)]) {
        return [self.selectedViewController shouldAutorotate];
    }
    else {
        return YES;
    }
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    if ([self.selectedViewController respondsToSelector:@selector(supportedInterfaceOrientations)]) {
        return [self.selectedViewController supportedInterfaceOrientations];
    }
    else if(DEVICE_IS_IPAD)
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
    else
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

-(UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    if ([self.selectedViewController respondsToSelector:@selector(supportedInterfaceOrientations)]) {
        return [self.selectedViewController preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation];
    }
    return 0;
}

@end

@implementation UINavigationController (AutoRotationForwarding)

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    if ([self.topViewController respondsToSelector:@selector(shouldAutorotate)]) {
        return [self.topViewController shouldAutorotate];
    }
    else {
        return YES;
    }
}

-(NSUInteger) supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    if([self.topViewController respondsToSelector:@selector(supportedInterfaceOrientations)])
    {
        return [self.topViewController supportedInterfaceOrientations];
    }
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

-(UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    if ([self.topViewController respondsToSelector:@selector(supportedInterfaceOrientations)]) {
        return [self.topViewController preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation];
    }
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft | UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight | UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown;
}
@end
```

and the code for the ViewController which I want to be Landscape only is :

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    if(DEVICE_IS_IPAD)
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
    else
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

-(UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
}
```

The Main issue is preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation is not at all called for UITabbarController or UINavigationBarController or even the view controller which I want to show.

Could you please let me know what am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

May be you forgot to add`supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow` to your AppDelegate?

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window{
    return  UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
```

Comment: anyways solved my problem by presentModalling it on the UINavigationController

Answer (score 1):

Beware of nil. I was following a similar approach of subclassing UINavigationController to relay the rotation messages to the topViewController. It worked great except the time the application launched. When you launch the application there is no topViewController (yet) but the OS needs to determine the supported orientation NOW AND for the the top-most viewController (the UINavigationController). If you fail to to provide an answer at the right time the UINavigationController will appear in the wrong orientation.

Note: PreferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation is not called for UINavigationController

> If your are using a UINavigationController as the root window
>   controller, it will be its shouldAutorotate &
>   supportedInterfaceOrientations which would be called.
>   [iOS6: supportedInterfaceOrientations not working (is invoked but the interface still rotates)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12447552/ios6-supportedinterfaceorientations-not-working-is-invoked-but-the-interface-s)