# Disable device rotation

Tags: objective-c, ios7, landscape, landscape-portrait

I have a problem and that is that in my application I allow the rotation of the device and also adapt the view, but in particular there is a view that I want to rotate the device is not change and look like when you do not allow rotation in application, meaning that it is always portrait, the problem is that being in landscape gives me view portrait ... Deputy capture

[image: Good picture]

[image: Bad picture]

Comment: Are you using split view controller ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS6: supportedInterfaceOrientations not working (is invoked but the interface still rotates)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12447552/ios6-supportedinterfaceorientations-not-working-is-invoked-but-the-interface-s)

Comment: within the same view I have subviews if they can rotate, is different to that post, in this post you can not rotate or view or subview