# iOS Error: Supported orientations has no common orientation with the application (iPhone)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiimagepickercontroller

**Using iOS 8.3**

I have a view in landscape mode, and i'm trying to open a portrait only view controller. every time i try to open it, the app crashes.

I have read this [official apple answer](https://devforums.apple.com/message/731764#731764) which basically recommends doing the following:

in the app delegate:

```
@implementation AppDelegate

-(NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
    else  /* iphone */
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
}
```

and in my controller:

```
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}
```

And so i have, and yet i still get this crash message:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'UIApplicationInvalidInterfaceOrientation', reason: 'Supported orientations has no common orientation with the application, and [PUUIAlbumListViewController shouldAutorotate] is returning YES
```

In the project general settings i have the following (which should not be changed according to apple's answer):

[image: settings]

I can see that these functions are in fact being called but nothing helps.
Any thoughts?

Some questions i read earlier:

[How to force a UIViewController to Portrait orientation in iOS 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12520030/how-to-force-a-uiviewcontroller-to-portait-orientation-in-ios-6)

[iOS6: supportedInterfaceOrientations not working (is invoked but the interface still rotates)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12447552/ios6-supportedinterfaceorientations-not-working-is-invoked-but-the-interface-s)

[Supported orientations has no common orientation with the application, and shouldAutorotate is returning YES'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12540597/supported-orientations-has-no-common-orientation-with-the-application-and-shoul)

Comment: In Xcode, check Portrait in addition to the two Landscape orientations (despite your comment that Apple claims it shouldn't be changed).

Comment: @rmaddy, i have other apps with this configuration, and indeed it should be marked out, otherwise the app start on portrait mode (and slicing the app), so this is not possible.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Synopsis:** `application(_:, supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow) -> Int` *does overwrite the General > Deployment Info. So you can ignore that .plist entirely once you provide `supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow` in the app delegate. See note about `UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait`.*

Having tried the code above every which way, in both Obj-C and Swift, the only times I get...

> 'UIApplicationInvalidInterfaceOrientation', reason: 'Supported orientations has no common orientation with the application, and [ViewController shouldAutorotate] is returning YES'

...is when:

1. using `UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait` instead of `UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait` (**mask** is the keyword here)
2. or `supportedInterfaceOrientations` returns a mask **not** listed in `supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow`

---

**A.** Place this block in the the class adopting the `UIApplicationDelegate` protocol (typically `AppDelegate.m` or `AppDelegate.swift`):

```
-(NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
    else  /* iphone */
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
}
```

`supportedInterfaceOrientations` will overwrite the *Deployment Info* and allow to dynamically differentiate iPhone from iPad at runtime.

---

**B.** Place this block in the `UIViewController` subclass for which you want a specific behavior (typically `CustomViewController.m` or `CustomViewController.swift`):

**Obj-C**

```
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

**Swift**

```
override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> Int {
    let supported = UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait.rawValue
    return Int(supported)
}
```

*Tested iOS 8.4*

Comment: Nicely explained, The problem was that i did not place the relevant chunk of code in the appDelegate.cpp and placed it in the image picker delegate, that's why it did not work. would you like to edit your answer so that i could accept it? (with the emphasis of placing the chunk of code in the appDelegate class ofc)

Answer (score 0):

Ugh, for me it was this line in my flutter main.dart blowing me up:

```
  await SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft]);
```