# View Controller in the "More" tab doesn't rotate, but it will if it's on the home row.

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, storyboard, orientation

I have an app built in storyboard that needs to support landscape mode in just one view controller. I decided to support iOS 6 after some issues with supporting iOS 5 and running iOS 6 on my phone. I used this Stack Overflow answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12505461/1050388 but I'm still seeing a weird quirk. (For those interested, my controller scheme is Tab Controller -> Navigation Controller -> TableViewController -> UIWebView. The UIWebView is the only VC I need to rotate.)

I blocked all but one VC from turning, but that VC is in the "More" tab. I initially had a quirk where this "More" VC would change orientation to landscape when rotated and then any subsequent VC would be in landscape, but I found this (https://stackoverflow.com/a/12526152/1050388) and creating a category for UINavigationController helped to solve that issue.

However, when I navigate to that tab in the "More" list, and turn the VC, it doesn't rotate. But when I click "Edit" and move that tab to the home row of the initial 4 tabs, it rotates just fine. If I move it back, it doesn't rotate. Anyone have an idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem stems from the fact that the More navigation controller is generated dynamically by iOS and is read-only.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITabBarController/moreNavigationController

It would be great if the technique of using a custom category would work here but based on your experience I guess it doesn't.

I also need better control of orientations for More tab views.  Please post anything you come up with.  Thanks.