# Rotate view controller

Tags: ios, iphone, youtube, orientation

I set my app that it should works only in portrait, now I'm showing a youtube video and I think it's better to see this video in landscape mode. I set my app with this flags:

[image]

How I can rotate the view when the video is playing? I display the video I'm using the [HCYoutubeParser](https://github.com/hellozimi/HCYoutubeParser) library. Can you help me?

**UPDATE**
storyboard:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check “Portrait”, "Landscape Left" and "Landscape Right" in the Deployment Info. In  the video player view controller, you support Portrait and Landscape, in your other view controllers only support Portrait.

You can refer to [Autorotate in iOS 6 has strange behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12526054/autorotate-in-ios-6-has-strange-behaviour) and 
[iOS 6 UITabBarController supported orientation with current UINavigation controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12504464/ios-6-uitabbarcontroller-supported-orientation-with-current-uinavigation-control)

Comment: Thank you for answer. I set the deployment info like what you said, now the video plays in landscape mode. Now how I can make portrait the other view controller? There's a code to do that?

Comment: @lucgian841 it depends on your whole view controller hierarchy. How about your view controller hierarchy?

Comment: @lucgian841 try shouldAutorotate return NO and supportedInterfaceOrientations return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait in all other view controllers

Comment: I tried what you say but no effects: the interface rotate... I tried to set portrait in storyboard too...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41883/discussion-between-lucgian841-and-chancy)