# iPad rientation is not working with SDK 6.1

Tags: ios6, monodevelop

i have iPad app which develop using monodevelop

Now i have problem with orientation with SDK 6.1

the orientation is not working with SDK 6.1 or on device /simulator 6.1

i tried to call ShouldAutoRotate function which return true but it not work

also function willrotate is not call at all !

i think there is another way to enable orientation with SDK 6

any help ?

Comment: Add code, what have you tried.....

Comment: i just return true on shouldAutoRotate function , which must enable auto orientation as i know

Comment: also if i run the same code with SDK less than 6.1 , the orientation is working ok !!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12775265/ios-6-shouldautorotate-is-not-being-called

Comment: Please check my answer , i already tried it and it is working ok

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In iOS6, auto rotate and orientation changes have changed , so i solved the problem using the following steps

1) You will need to assign a root view controller to your main application window on FinishedLaunching.

So if previously like me you have this in your `FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app)` method in main.cs:

```
window.AddSubview(mainVC.View);
```

Replace it with this:

```
window.RootViewController = mainVC;
```

2) Replace this:

```
public override bool ShouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation (UIInterfaceOrientation toInterfaceOrientation)
```

With these two functions:

```
public override bool ShouldAutorotate()
 {
    return true;
 }

public override UIInterfaceOrientationMask GetSupportedInterfaceOrientations()
{

    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.All;
}
```

3- you can fire the rotation action using `WillRotate` function

Comment: Nice! works the same in iOS (using the iOS native functions) too!