# supporting Portrait Orientation mode for UIViewController in storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios6, xcode4.6

I created UIViewController using storyboard and Linked it to UIViewController class.

I would like to make my UIViewController only support Portrait Orientation, I tried the blow code, but it seems it doesn't work. my UIViewController still rotate.

Do I need to change any property in storyboard?

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {

     return ((interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) || (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` is deprecated in iOS6,  you should use `shouldAutoRotate` & `supportedInterfaceOrientations`.

Try like this in your viewController.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return NO;
}

- (BOOL)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

Comment: I tried it, but its still rotating... do I need to do anything in storyboard?

Comment: In your project settings you could set supported orientation only to Portrait.

Comment: yes, but I have other UIViewController which require to support Landscape mode as well.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here:
[iOS 6 shouldAutorotate: is NOT being called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12775265/ios-6-shouldautorotate-is-not-being-called)

**my UIViewControoller is managed by UINavigationController which control it orientation in iOS 6:**

**Now, iOS containers (such as UINavigationController) do not consult their children to determine whether they should autorotate. By default, an app and a view controller’s supported interface orientations are set to UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll for the iPad idiom and UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown for the iPhone idiom.**

I had to subclass UINavigationController with the new **shouldAutorotate** and **supportedInterfaceOrientations**

I saw other post prefer to add category instead of subclassing. but for me, subclassing works fine.

Comment: Good if you have solved your problem. you did not mention about navigationcontroller, I have answered this kind of questions multiple times about sub classing

Comment: sorry .. i didn't know  when I asked the question that it make difference when the UIViewControlor is managed by navigationcontroller.