# Auto rotate in iOS7 and iOS8

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, autorotate, landscape-portrait

I am developing an application which is in portrait mode.
But I want one view controller should display in landscape as well as in portrait mode.

I tried the following code but it doesn't work **(not called)**.

```
- (BOOL) shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}
- (BOOL) shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12775265/ios-6-shouldautorotate-is-not-being-called try this

Comment: @Dheeraj Singh unfortunately none of methods called.

Comment: we have already did the same thing for navigationController
self.window.rootViewController = self.objNavigationController;

Comment: does shouldAutoRotate get called.

Comment: no that doesn't called

Comment: if you set in your iOS app plist supported interface orientation property only to portrait - then this won't be called, otherwise it might be a problem of view controller being wrapped inside `UITabBarController` or `UINavigationController`

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to set in your plist all the orientations your app supports, this can be done in the 'General' tab in the project under "Deployment Info", for example:
[image]

Then, you can use the method `supportedInterfaceOrientations`,

I assume you are presenting the view controller modally, so simply override it, on the presenting viewController, which need to be only in portrait use:

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

and in your presented viewController, which should also supports landscape, use: (or whatever orientation mask you would like)

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
}
```

**P.S** - there is a different behavior for viewController that is presented modally and for a viewController that push in a navigationController stack:

- **modalViewController** will call its own `supportedInterfaceOrientations`, and will support these orientations
- **pushedViewController** will call its navigationController `supportedInterfaceOrientations`, and will support these orientation.

So, if you are presenting the viewController modally, you need to override its own `supportedInterfaceOrientations`, but if you push this viewController, you need to set some BOOL property in the navigationController, so it will know which orientations to supports. 
I advise you to present this viewController modally, it's more natural to use modalViewController for different device orientations.

**P.S #2**: about `shouldAutorotate`: if it returns 'NO', than `supportedInterfaceOrientations` is not called, so return 'YES'. It only says, if to rotate automatically when the device rotates. if it returns 'NO', you need to explicit rotate the viewController.

Well I hope I helped and didn't write an answer that is completely not regarded to what you asked... :)