# How to manually set the device orientation when App Deployment Info portrait is locked?

Tags: ios, iphone, landscape-portrait, portrait, uideviceorientation

I dont want my app to be landscaped and always be porttrait.So i made my app **Deployment Info** to set portrait only. but when i need to display any image or videos in my app,i need landscape mode for better display.

I can detect the device orientation change by

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(orientationChanged:)
 name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification
 object:[UIDevice currentDevice]];

- (void) orientationChanged:(NSNotification *)note
{
UIDevice * device = note.object;
switch(device.orientation)
{
    case UIDeviceOrientationPortrait:
        /*  */
        break;

    case UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
        /*  */
        break;
    case UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
       /*  */
       break;

    case UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight:
       /*  */
       break;
    default:
        break;
};
}
```

But how do i manually change my device orientation even when App Deployment Info portrait is locked ?

This **doesnt worked**

```
NSNumber *value=[NSNumber numberWithInt: UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft];
[[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:value forKey:@"orientation"];
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please enable Portrait & Landscape from your project setting. Then use below method for all viewcontroller to autorotation turn off -

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return NO;
}
```

Then use below method to all except LandScapeViewControler -

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:
     [NSNumber numberWithInteger: UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait]
                                forKey:@"orientation"];
}
```

Use below method for LandScapeViewControler -

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

        [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:
         [NSNumber numberWithInteger: UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft]
                                    forKey:@"orientation"];
    }
```

If you are using NavigationController and TabBarController then please use category to turn off autorotation .

Hope this will be help you.

Comment: why do need this method **LandScapeViewControler--- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated** ? can't i just  put shouldAutorotate to **YES** in  **LandScapeViewControler** and it can rotate to LandScapeleft,right,portrait,upsidedown.

Comment: Incase of you want to restrict LandScapeViewControler only to LandScape mode. Otherwise you can return YES

Comment: unfortunately, my **shouldAutorotate** is not being called .you know why?

Comment: Please check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12775265/ios-6-shouldautorotate-is-not-being-called

Comment: thanks got.it .from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12260261/shouldautorotatetointerfaceorientation-not-being-called-in-ios-6

Answer (score 6):

Two steps:

1. Include landscape to the deployment
2. In each view controller `viewDidLoad` you need to include:

   ```
   //Swift
   let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeLeft.rawValue
   UIDevice.currentDevice().setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")

   //Obj-C
   NSNumber *value = [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft];
   [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:value forKey:@"orientation"];
   ```

See also: [How do I programmatically set device orientation in iOS7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20987249/how-do-i-programmatically-set-device-orientation-in-ios7)

Comment: I dont need landscape for my app except photos and videos. Including "landscape to the deployment" make no sense.

Comment: If you have any scenario where you do you can't prevent it entirely. Presumably videos and Images are displayed in a view controller so only set that one to Landscape

Comment: im using a QLPreviewController to view files and you deviated from my question "How to set orientation even portrait lock in **Deployment Info** is **ON** ?

Comment: If you set it in the deployment info your target will not support the unchecked options. So what I am telling you is that you can't do it the way you are trying to do it.

Comment: got your point.and im trying to  1.check portrait and landscape in deployment info                                                                                             2.- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return NO;
} in all views except landscape view and forcing portrait default in viewdidload of all views except landscape. but this too didnt work :(  @Mikael

Comment: You can use landscape views even though you have set on portrait in project settings. You do not need to set landscape mode.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of forcing orientation change you should subclass a navigation controller which is landscape and use it by presenting. Then your app would always be portrait as you want it. It will landscape when you use this navigation controller.

```
#import "RotationAwareNavigationController.h"

@implementation RotationAwareNavigationController

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return NO;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}
```

You should call it like below;

```
RotationAwareNavigationController *navController = [[RotationAwareNavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:aViewController];
[self presentViewController:navController animated:NO completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated answer for Swift 3+:

```
let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.landscapeLeft.rawValue
UIDevice.current.setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")
```

Comment: Mostly working, but got a few (2) crashes with this during testing. I guess not a big issue; but still this is obviously an "undocumented" feature and should be treated as such. I will look for another way.