# How to lock rotation orientation for portrait in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiinterfaceorientation

I am new in iOS and I am facing a problem regarding the rotation. I just need to lock the Single view controller rotation in portrait. I am using a code like this

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:NO];
    [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO];
    NSNumber *value = [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight];
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:value forKey:@"orientation"];
}
```

And this work fine in Landscape but not in the portrait.How can I used this for portrait. I have tried portrait method like this.

1. UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait
2. UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait
3. UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown
4. UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown
   But none work for me. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26357162/how-to-force-view-controller-orientation-in-ios-8

Comment: @UmairAfzal that is same what I have Used.

Comment: What is your iOS version ?

Comment: @JamshedAlam iOS 9.3.5

Answer (score 0):

Use this code only Portrait orientation view controller, tested on IOS 9 OR later.

// Lock orientation to Portrait

```
-(UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

-(NSUInteger)navigationControllerSupportedInterfaceOrientations:(UINavigationController *)navigationController {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

OR

```
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
 return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
 return NO;
}
```

Check this ([iOS 6 shouldAutorotate: is NOT being called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12775265/ios-6-shouldautorotate-is-not-being-called)) answer

Comment: Where to call this method and How?

Comment: It show me warning conflict return type in Implement of 'Support Orientition'. In your first code.

Comment: @Muju Check Edit.

Comment: @Muju it's only warning not error please run this code and follow this link.