# Edits to app delegate to lock in portrait ios 5 and 6

Tags: objective-c, ios, device-orientation

I'm having a few issues with stopping rotation in both ios 5 and ios 6. I want to lock the app into portrait. I'm using a nav bar based application, but the nav bars on some pages are hidden (if that makes a difference).

I'm not quite sure what edits to make in the app delegate, to disable autorotation and lock it into portrait to target these versions of iOs, any ideas?

Comment: Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12260261/shouldautorotatetointerfaceorientation-not-being-called-in-ios-6/12580217#12580217

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked .info plist file?,if not then see supported inteface orientation and discard orientations which you don't want in your app.