# Wont rotate with new xCode

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, rotation, iphone-3gs

I've got a problem with the latest version of xCode. Whenever i create a new Single view application and I deploy this to my iPhone 3GS, it won't rotate the app (to landscape). When I deploy the exact same version to my iPhone 4, it does rotate the app (to landscape). I've tried installing other apps on the 3GS, and those apps rotate just fine. Also older apps that we've developed are rotating just fine on the 3GS.

I just select create new project in xCode and directly deploy it to the test phones (without any code modifications, just changed the iOS deployment target to 5.0 and the Deployment target too (to 5.0)).

The iPhone 3GS runs version 5.1.1, the iPhone 4 runs on 6.0.1. My xCode version is 4.5

Has anybody experienced this problem before, and knows how to fix it?

Comment: Maybe this question can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12396545/ios-6-apps-how-to-deal-with-iphone-5-screen-size/12397738#12397738

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean that you changed the Base SDK to iOS 6.0? I've had the same issue when I did just that. In iOS 6, auto rotation has changed and method `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` is deprecated. See this post for details about this change: [shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation not being called in iOS 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12260261/shouldautorotatetointerfaceorientation-not-being-called-in-ios-6)

Comment: No, i said i did change it to 5.0 ;)

Comment: Sorry, I meant "Base SDK", not "Deployment Target" (updated my answer now). But maybe you did too! :)

Comment: Sorry for my late response! I eventually fixed it by starting a new xCode project and migrated my code to the new project. That fixed it. I guess it probably had something to do with the Base SDK indeed.. Thanks for your help! :)