# Embeded youtube not playing in landscape mode (iOS6)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiwebview, ios6

I have a UIViewcontroller that push a second UIViewcontroller. The second UIViewcontroller has a UIWebview: some text, and some videos from youtube url (embed). When i click on the video the player is opening and the screen is still on portrait mode, and not rotates to landscape.

The videos work correctly on ios5 with the function:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(movieIsPlaying:) name:@"UIMoviePlayerControllerDidEnterFullscreenNotification" object:nil];

- (void)movieIsPlaying:(NSNotification *)notification
{

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight | UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft animated:NO];
}
```

The problem occurs only with ios6.

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quote from Apple's iOS SDK, XCode4.5+ (see `UIViewController` Class Reference, Handling View Rotations):

> In iOS 6, your app supports the interface orientations defined in your
>   app’s Info.plist file. A view controller can override the
>   supportedInterfaceOrientations method to limit the list of supported
>   orientations. Generally, the system calls this method only on the root
>   view controller of the window or a view controller presented to fill
>   the entire screen; child view controllers use the portion of the
>   window provided for them by their parent view controller and no longer
>   participate in directly in decisions about what rotations are
>   supported.

Also in iOS6, `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` method of `UIViewController` class is already deprecated.

So in your root view controller, you do the ff:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
  return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
  return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

Btw, "root view controller" is any `UIViewController` subclass you set as the rootViewController of your appDelegate's window object. You usually do this in the appDelegate's `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
  // Override point for customization after application launch.
  self.window.rootViewController = [FFDashboardController create];
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
  return YES;
}
```

also check this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12260261/shouldautorotatetointerfaceorientation-not-being-called-in-ios-6/13137994#13137994)