# orientation not supporting in ios6 devices

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios6

i have an application build on xcode 4.2 , which supports only portrait orientation, it works fine with all devices except ios6 .. In Ios 6 devices it is showing both orientations .. I need only portrait orientation .. i am using navigation controller .. 
IN appdelegate::

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{

      return ([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]==UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}


- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
     return (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait);
}
```

in other viewControllers ::

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return YES;
}

- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    DisplayFunctionName;
    NSLog(@"orientation: %d",self.interfaceOrientation);
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
    {
        return (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll);
    }
    else
    {
        return (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait);
    }
}
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    DisplayFunctionName;
    NSLog(@"orientation: %d",interfaceOrientation);
      return (interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);

}
```

Comment: In other viewControllers, in `shouldAutoRotate` method, try replacing `return YES;` with `return ([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]==UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);`.

Comment: If you are only need the portrait orientation in your application it is better to disable all other orientations in your application plist configuration.

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In IOS6 handling of Orientation is difficult is case when you want portrait orientation for some views and for some you want landscape orientation,  but its very easy if you want only one orientation support for entire app. simple go to **Supporting Files** and then open the info.plist in your app and remove all other orientation except one that you want.. below are few screen shot which help you to fix your issue

[image]

[image]

after removing all other orientation your info.plist will be looks like below
[image]

i hope it works for you.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

iOS 6

**shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation**:
is deprecated and replaced by

**shouldAutorotate**

Check this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/14938444/305135

Answer (score 0):

Try using these ,

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}

- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}
```