# IOS Device orientation is not working cocos2d view when UIView controller is on top

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, cocos2d-iphone, orientation

i had a cocos2d game having some UIViewController's view.

1) when only cocos2d view is present orientation changes works fine
2) when only UIViewController's view is present orientation changes works fine

But when i have a UIViewController on top of cocos2d view, the orientation change effect does't propagates to cocos2d view i.e UIViewController is rotated and cocos2d remains the same.

I have tried bunch of solutions, please see im using cocos2d 2.x version.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Use custom class (UIViewController or UIView - according to your need) then override the orientation methods...then use NSNotification & NSNotification​Center to observe the change from Cocos2D class and change the orientation of custom class accordingly.

Given below links might help you along the way:

- http://www.raywenderlich.com/4817/how-to-integrate-cocos2d-and-uikit
- http://nshipster.com/nsnotification-and-nsnotificationcenter/
- [shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation not being called in iOS 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12260261/shouldautorotatetointerfaceorientation-not-being-called-in-ios-6)

Comment: Let say i get the notification of orientation change, how do i change the cocos2d orientation manually ?

Comment: First You need to set:[[CCDirector sharedDirector] setDelegate: self]; then In that same file add this:- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation{
return (interfaceOrientation == YourInterfaceOrientation);
}

Comment: thanks but shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation is not being called